# Why there is 1px background color outside the border

Tags: html, css

I was writing CSS battle https://cssbattle.dev/play/9,

here is my solution: https://codepen.io/tinac/pen/oNMKZZr

But I found that the output is 98.6% match instead of 100%. The reason seems is there is a 1px border with background color #4CAAB3 outside my square:

```css
#s2 {
  background: #4CAAB3;
  border: 50px solid #222730;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Why there is 1px border with background color outside of my 50px border?
I checked the box-model in dev tool, it looks fine. Please help, thanks in advance.

[image: outpout]

Comment: Try adding `border-radius: 1px;`

Comment: @RohadBokhar OMG, it's working! Could you write an answer and explain more about why it's working? I want to mark it as accepted

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have idea why is that working, might be a bug? I'm not an expert on this field. I got it from trying every possible css code that have something to do with border from your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a side-effect of
`transform: rotate(45deg)`. Try using `backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: I tried adding `backface-visibility: hidden` to `#s2`, but not working. But I think your direction is right.

Answer (score -1):

Use css important

background:#4CAAB3 !important;

Comment: it's not an issue about CSS priority.